# Authentication with facebook login with server side

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate users with facebook login. It's easy to login a user with javascript sdk. But I wanted to integrate with my asp.net server side authentication system.

I think a method like this:

- first user login with facebook client sdk
- then made a request to server with access token, email and user id
- then made a request to facebook graph api with access token and user id
- then compared response with user email data with i had
- so i make it logged in with asp.net session

What do you think?

Edit: Or is it ok if I just use application specific user id with registered email?

Comment: This is not the place to ask people for their opinion ("What do you think?"). Facebook's documentation on ["manually building a login flow"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2) explains the steps required to implement a facebook login flow. There is also an [unofficial C# SDK for Facebook](http://facebooksdk.net/)

Comment: really, are you serious?

Comment: Yes I am serious. [This FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) explains what kind of subjective questions are permissible on this site. I don't think that yours qualifies, as it is too open ended. The resources I provided were meant to help you rephrase your question in a more constructive way that is less open ended.